# "Много кто" или "многие, кто"

Tags: синтаксис

Можно ли сказать: "Много кто любит поесть сладкое: взрослые и дети, мальчики и девочки" или нужно так: "Многие, кто любит поесть сладкое: ..."? Нам учитель исправил на «Многие, кто...» и посчитал за ошибку. Мне кажется «Много (подлежащее) кто любит (сказуемое)» — и незачем их разделять; а вот если «многие (подлежащее), кто любит сладкое (уточнение): мальчики и девочки… (перечисление)» — тогда сказуемого нет вообще. Помогите решить эту дилемму, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

**Много кто  любит поесть сладкое: взрослые и дети, мальчики и девочки.**

Сравнить: **Многие любят** поесть сладкое: взрослые и дети, мальчики и девочки.

***Много кто*** ― устойчивый оборот со значение "многие" в роли подлежащего.

Примеры:

Особенный дом. **Много кто** туда приходил. Рабиндранат Тагор приходил. [Н. К. Рерих. Листы дневника (1945)]

― Не помню, ― ответил Пырьев. ― У меня **много кто** ночевал. (Из тетрадки в клеточку. [Юрий Никулин. Мое любимое кино (1979)]

Answer (score 0):

**Много кто любит поесть сладкое: взрослые и дети, мальчики и девочки.**

Но если предложение имеет продолжение, то ситуция может быть иной, например:

**Многие, кто любит поесть сладкое: взрослые и дети, мальчики и девочки, — не обращают внимания на предупреждения врачей о вреде лишних калорий.**